# Firebase won't load Angular project when using scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'

Tags: angular, firebase

I've tried deploying my app with it and it just shows up as an empty page. When running it on local host, its behaves as expected.
It deploys normally when i remove { scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' }

This is my app-routing.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ItemsComponent } from './items/items.component';
import { ShopComponent } from './shop/shop.component';
import { ShoppingCartComponent } from './shopping-cart/shopping-cart.component';
import { ItemPageComponent } from './item-page/item-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/shop', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'shop', component: ShopComponent },
  { path: 'cart', component: ShoppingCartComponent },
  { path: 'items', component: ItemsComponent },
  { path: 'product/:id', component: ItemPageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

firebase.json file

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database-security.json"
  },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "site": "v34l",
      "public": "src",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "V34L",
      "source": ".",
      "frameworksBackend": {}
    }
  ]
}
```